# Matlab-Handle two subploted images

Tags: matlab, subplot

I can use the `subplot` to display multiple images in the same window. for example, I have two images displayed by:

```
figure,
subFig1=subplot(1,2,1) 
surface(rawx,rawy,rawz) % 3D object 

subFig2=subplot(1,2,2)
plot(x,z) %profile of the surface.
```

Assuming rawx, rawy,rawz is the orginal data and x,y,z is measured data.  I am using the iteration '`for`' to read the measured data.

During the loop, is it possible to hold subFig1 and plot measured profile on top of the surface, and in the mean time, subFig2 can still display the profile in 2D and refresh when the new measurements coming.

I guess this can be done by different handle. However, I can't find any cue so far. please help.

Answer (score 4):

Axes in a subplot behave the same way than in figures. The last subplot called is still active.

In your case, the solution would be:

```
figure, 
subFig1=subplot(1,2,1) 
surface(rawx,rawy,rawz) 

subFig2=subplot(1,2,2)
hold on
plot(x,z)

for ...
  x= ... % your new value
  z= ...
  plot(x,z) % subplot 122 still active and still hold
end
```

Comment: Yes, hold on will allow me to plot new figures on 122. But how can I plot new figures on top of the 121 and 122. Fig. 122 includes the measurement data and curve fitting results in 2D space. Also, Fig. 121 can display the 3D object plus the fitted curve on top of it.

Comment: Just retype `subplot 122; hold on` (or 121) according to the subfigure you want.

Comment: Note that if this answer correspond to your needs, you can accept it.

Comment: finally find the solution. this can be achieve using axes.,</br>